# How to alert and redirect using sweet alert in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sweetalert

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
"alert", 
"alert('User details saved successfully');window.location ='frmDisplayUsers.aspx';", 
true);
```

Comment: So, whats wrong with current code.

Comment: Nothing wrong .
it is showing normal alert only i want it in sweet alert

Comment: ok so, integrate it with sweet-alert, checkout documentation on their site

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522843/sweetalert-confirmation-dialog-with-asp-net-listview-delete you will find your answer here

Comment: i am beginner so difficult to understand it
can you guyz be more specific

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a referene to the SweetAlert library in the head section of the page:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Then you need to change your code to this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
"alert",
"swal('User details saved successfully').then((value) => { window.location ='frmDisplayUsers.aspx'; });", 
true);
```

Comment: can i add more swal() properities like auto close and other stuffss????

Comment: yes you can, like this: swal('User details saved successfully', { OPTIONS GO HERE }).then(...) here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945646/sweet-alert-timer-done-function

Answer (score -1):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "swal('Done !!!','User details saved successfully','success').then((value) => { window.location ='frmDisplayUsers.aspx'; });", true);
```

this was what i wanted.....